# Navigate site.com studio page to a force.com page

Tags: visualforce, site.com, redirect, navigation

I have a Site.com page and a Visualforce page There is a link in the Site page which needs to redirect to the Visualforce and vice-versa. Is this possible? How?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add the VF page to a force.com site and redirect to the site page. And if you need to redirect back to the site.com page, you'll have to add the site.com page URL after publishing the site. If you give the URL before publishing it, it might ask for authentication. I hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want a clickable link to appear on each page, or a redirect to fire?